# Laravel and Wordpress on same server/domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I am trying to host a WordPress site inside a Laravel(5.1) project. I have the following structure (stripped down some)

```
├── app
├── config
├── public
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── wordpress -> ../wordpress
│   └── .htaccess
├── resources
├── storage
├── vendor
└── wordpress
    ├── index.php
    ├── wp-admin
    ├── wp-config.php
    ├── wp-includes
    └── .htaccess
```

The vhost document root is public.

The Wordpress should catch everything that falls through the .htaccess. But for example /login should go to laravel. When my project grows i intend to add more rules to catch requests for Laravel. I have the following .htaccess file in /public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule "^/login" "index.php" [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "wordpress/$1" [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when i make the request to /login i still end up with the wordpress page. Here is a part of the log:

```
 add path info postfix: /var/www/public/login -> /var/www/public/login/
 strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/public/login/ -> login/
 applying pattern '^/login' to uri 'login/'
 add path info postfix: /var/www/public/login -> /var/www/public/login/
 strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/public/login/ -> login/
 applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'login/'
 RewriteCond: input='/var/www/public/login' pattern='!-d' => matched
 RewriteCond: input='/var/www/public/login' pattern='!-f' => matched
 rewrite 'login/' -> 'wordpress/login/'
 add per-dir prefix: wordpress/login/ -> /var/www/public/wordpress/login/
 strip document_root prefix: /var/www/public/wordpress/login/ -> /wordpress/login/
 internal redirect with /wordpress/login/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

It seems like the rewriting does not stop at the [L] flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your logs the first condition didn't match:

```
applying pattern '^/login' to uri 'login/'
```

`login/` doesn't start with `/`

So you need to change your rule to

```
RewriteRule "^login/" "index.php" [L]
```

Comment: you should also give the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939580/laravel-and-wordpress-on-same-server-domain , if someone is not in this community, he can still get it easily .